# Is it okay to mix in storage and type qualifiers anywhere inside multi-word C-type?

Tags: c, syntax, language-lawyer

I checked, this works:

```
long static int const unsigned my_variable = 123;
```

I understand this is silly, but why do we even have such a possibility in the first place?

The whole idea of type names being multi-word is bad enough, but now I learn the words allowed to be in any order and to be interleaved with other qualifiers?

Any novice learning C's `unsigned int`, `const short` will wonder is `unsigned` a type or is it some sort of qualifier like `const` is? Is there `unsigned float` then, etc.

All this seems so unnecessarily more complicated than the obvious use of some one-word tokens for all types like `uint`, `ulongint` that it begs me to question if I understand something properly?

Comment: This works exactly the same as adjectives and nouns in a human language, and has the same motivation.

Comment: @zwol a bit idealistic for a system programming language :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it because the standard says you can, and the standard says so because the pre-standard implementations allowed it (albeit the pre-standard implementations did not recognize `signed` as a keyword or `long long` as a type).  See C11 [§6.7.2 Type specifiers ¶2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p2):

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

One of the multisets given in the list is:

> `long long`, `signed long long`, `long long int`, or `signed long long int`

The wording means that you can also use

```
int long signed long
```

as a type name.  It's not good practice, but you can do it.

Note that specifying the storage class anywhere other than first is obsolescent — [§6.11.5 Storage class specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5) notes:

> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

That means your example using `long static int const unsigned my_variable = 123;` is using an obsolescent feature.  It would be better to use:

```
static long int const unsigned my_variable = 123;
```

and still better to put the type information contiguously:

```
static const unsigned long int my_variable = 123;
```

or

```
static unsigned long int const my_variable = 123;
```

(both are legitimate; I prefer the first).  And you could drop the `int` from all the versions without affecting the meaning.

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive! So it's mostly for legacy reasons as I understand it? Most modern languages prefer more restrictive syntax for such things and one-word tokens for types. No practical reasons for why C gone this way.

Comment: Yes, primarily legacy support.  C90 was a success because it invalidated as few C programs as possible — it succeeded incredibly well in doing that.  Later standards have added more restrictions, and C23 when it is released will remove the original K&R notation for function definitions and declarations — `extern void somefunc();` changes meaning from 'function returning nothing with an unspecified (but not variadic) argument list' to 'function returning nothing and taking no arguments'.  This will break old code compiled to conform with C23.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to Jonathan Leffler's answer.

A quote from [Programming on Purpose](https://seriouscomputerist.atariverse.com/media/pdf/book/Programming%20on%20Purpose.pdf) comes to mind (emphasis added):

> The (unfortunately **very lax**) rules of C let the programmer write any of:

```
register int X; 
register X; 
int register X;
```